# Facebook SDK doesn't return an email from user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I see there are many questions about that here, but there isn't solution for my problem. I have PHP site with Facebook login and I need to get an email address, but Facebook SDK doesn't return it. This is JS code:

```
 $(function(){
   $('.fb_reg_btn').click(function(){
       FB.login(function(response){

           FB.api('/me?fields=email', function(response) {
               window.top.location ="http://redirecturlhere";
           });
           return false;
       });
       return false;
   });
});
```

And this is PHP, when redirect:

```
        try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

        $response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email,first_name,last_name', 
        $accessToken->getValue());
        $result = $response->getGraphUser();

        var_dump($result);


    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
         When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
         When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

It is standart login with Facebook and it works fine, except that it doesnt return email address, but it returns other values like first name, name, last name, id. The result of var_dump is (edited):

> object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser)#37 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(12) "name edited" ["first_name"]=> string(5) "name edited" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "name edited" ["id"]=> string(17) "numbers" } }

How to get and the emaill address ?
I know for sure that the user has email and I am using same code, but another FB app for other site with FB login and there it returns and the email. I tried to change 'fields' with 'scope', but is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `email` permission in the scope parameter in your login process. For example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app
        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, function(response) {
           window.top.location = 'http://redirecturlhere';
       });
    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Also, make sure the email is approved on Facebook.

Comment: Same and the email is approved.

Comment: what means "same"? you did forget to add the scope parameter in your code. debug the response and make sure you actually get asked for the email permission in the login popup.

Comment: I mean the result is same with your example. No email, but other fields like first name, last, id etc (this fields that I added like params, except the email).There is result with no email. Same code with same FB profile for logging works in another project. The only different thing here is the FB app, but is with same settings, created with same FB user.

Comment: so do you get asked for the email permission in the login popup?

Comment: if it works in another project with the exact same code, you should consider filing a bug. also, make sure the app is public.